# flutter error Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

I am trying to make the splashscreen display for 5 seconds only but I have the following error.[flutter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GrCh.png)

my dart code[splashScreen code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAP74.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert SplashScreen class into StateFulWidget.
then inside initState() navigate after 4 seconds.

```
 @override
 void initState() {
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4)).then((value) {
  Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
   return const HomePage();
  },));
});
super.initState();
}
```